# add multiple same primary key in one row

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa

i have created `PromoCode` table as follow:

**`PromoCode` table:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PromoCode", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "promocode_name", name = "UK_PromoCode_PromocodeName") })
public class PromoCode {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@NotNull
private String promocode_name;
private String description;

@Type(type = "text")
private String terms_and_conditions;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<User> user;
private Date creation_date;
private Date end_date;
private String promotion_type;
private int uses;
private float discount;
private int count;
private boolean enable;
```

this create another table `promo_code_user` which have field `promo_code_id` and `user_userid` the `user_userid` is `Unique`.
i want to add same `userid` multiple time because as per my `PromoCode` table if `uses` is more than 1.
but i can't able to add same `userid`mutiple userid because it `unique` in `promo_code_user` table.

is there any other way so can add multiple same `userid` for particular `PromoCode` code.

i have also try code for filter the `promocode` :

```
List<PromoCode> deleteList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<PromoCode> promoCodeList = bicycleService.getAcivatedPromo();
    System.out.println("List is : " + promoCodeList);
    int currentUses = 0;

    // filter the promo codes
    if (promoCodeList != null && !promoCodeList.isEmpty()) {
        for (PromoCode promoCode : promoCodeList) {
            final int uses = promoCode.getUses();
            List<User> userSet = promoCode.getUser();

            for (User user : userSet) {
                if (user.equals(bikeuser)) {
                    currentUses++;
                    if (uses >= currentUses) {
                        deleteList.add(promoCode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        promoCodeList.removeAll(deleteList);
        return promoCodeList;
    }
```

If anyone suggest other design that very helpful me.

Thank you

Comment: It's unique because you said it was a OneToMany association. So one promo code has many users, and a user has one promo code. If you want a user to have many promo codes, then the association should be a ManyToMany.

Comment: Thanks..Now it's working  @JBNizet